# Why won't my layers appear when I try to load an image with J2ME?

Tags: java, java-me

I'm trying to load an image. The program compiles but the layers don't appear.

These are the errors I get:

> TRACE: , startApp threw an Exception
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
>
> > at javax.microedition.lcdui.game.TiledLayer.(), bci=66
> >     at RRCanvas.start(RRCanvas.java:32)
> >     at RRashlMIDlet.startApp(RRashlMIDlet.java:16)

and this is the code on those lines:

```
try {
        trackLayer = new TiledLayer(12, 48, Image.createImage("/map.png"), 48, 48);
        grassLayer = new TiledLayer(12, 48, Image.createImage("/map.png"), 48, 48);
        checkpointLayer = new TiledLayer(12 , 48, Image.createImage("/map.png"), 48, 48);
    }
        catch (IOException e) {
      System.err.println("Failed loading images!");
    }
```

and

```
canvas.start();
```

Comment: Is this somehow related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5405073/java-j2me-layers-problem ? Or is the similar title pure coincidence?

Comment: nope dont know anything bout that

Answer (score 1):

The exception is being thrown in the TiledLayer constructor. [Here](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/game/TiledLayer.html#TiledLayer%28int,%20int,%20javax.microedition.lcdui.Image,%20int,%20int%29) is the documentation for that constructor. Have a look at the possible reasons why that exception might be thrown, and use the debugger to find out if the arguments to any of the constructor calls have those problems.